# Relative Layout onCLick change background and stroke color

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

When I am clicking on relative layout, the background and stroke color is not changing. I mentioned all keyword i.e. `android:state_focused="true"`, `android:state_pressed="true"`, `android:state_selected="true"`, but nothing happened.  What is wrong in my code. Kindly help.

Relative Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/plan2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle_plan"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:focusable="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                        android:text="₹5000"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />


                </RelativeLayout>
```

shape_rectangle_plan - XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <size android:height="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#12FDB559" />
            <stroke android:width="0.8dp" android:color="@color/color2" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <size android:height="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#12FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

MainActivity:

```
relative_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                relative_layout.setSelected(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't specify anywhere to notify relative layout change the background colour when clicked. I believe the code you used in your selecter doesn't work in that way.

Comment: Use Ripple effect

Comment: Venkatesh Talacheeru, I edited the question, plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true">
        <shape>
            <size android:height="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#12FDB559" />
            <stroke android:width="0.8dp" android:color="@color/color2" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:state_selected="false">
        <shape>
            <size android:height="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#12FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In your class:

```
relative_layout.setOnClickListener {
          relative_layout.setSelected(true)
}
```

Comment: @Gaurav Dureja, My pleasure!